# I'm trying to run task chains parallel. How efficient is my current solution

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, task

My code is an async api call, and looks like the example below

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskObject>> GetTaskObjects()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<TaskObject>>();
    var shizzle = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return new TaskObject("1"); });
    var shizzle2 = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return new TaskObject("2"); });

    tasks.Add(shizzle.ContinueWith(part1 => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return part1.Result; }));
    tasks.Add(shizzle2.ContinueWith(part1 => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return part1.Result; }));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
}
```

The controller is a Stateless Service Fiber Web Api that makes some calls to a statefull service. Is this a good solution? Are there beter ones? Are the async and await keywords even necessary if this is an api call?

Comment: You almost never want to use `Task.Run` on a server, because using multiple threads per request can *very* quickly kill your scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskObject>> GetTaskObjects2()
{
        var tasks = new List<Task<TaskObject>>();
        var shizzle = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return new TaskObject("1"); });
        var shizzle2 = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return new TaskObject("2"); });


        //Add your task to the collection
        tasks.Add(shizzle);
        tasks.Add(shizzle2);

        //wait for when all task are finished and it will return the data.
        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

> If this line of codes are really awaitable

```
/// At this point, all two tasks are running at the same time.
var shizzle = DoShizzleAsync();
var shizzle2 = DoShizzle2Async();

await Task.WhenAll(shizzle2, shizzle);
```

See [Stephen Cleary blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more information

Comment: alright, so how does this work when using chained tasks? Would it be easier to write separate async functions for these?

Comment: @martijn: Yes. Use separate `async` methods with `await` to replace the (dangerous and low-level) `ContinueWith`.

Comment: why is `ContinueWith` considered dangerous?